# How to disable Windows 8 lock screen?

Tags: windows-8, lockscreen

So I took a plunge and installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview on my main home PC. So far so good, but there is one annoyance - the system "locks" the computer after a period of inactivity causing me to re-enter my password.

I really would like to avoid this, but have no idea how.
I already tried the power settings (no pass on wake up) and the screen saver settings with no luck. Is this some sort of bug, or am I missing something?

P.S. In this case I favor convenience over security.

Comment: this belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Use Screen Saver Settings and uncheck "On resume, display logon screen".

Comment: As Thomas said: This doesn't belong on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-  Use the +R to bring the Run command, type gpedit.msc and hit Enter. This will start the Local Group Policy Editor that is extremely useful to control many Windows settings.

2-  From the left pane, navigate through: Administrative Templates > Control Panel and select Personalization. In the right side you’ll have all the settings that you can control in this section.

3-  Choose “Do not display the lock screen” setting and double-click it.

4-  As you noticed, this policy setting controls if the lock screen in Windows 8 appears or not to all users. This is pretty similar to the Ctrl+ALT+Del feature in Windows. Check Enabled, then click Apply and OK.

Source
http://tutorials.ebasio.com/189/disable-stop-lock-screen-feature.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the Windows 8 lock screen, you can do that from local group policy Editor.
You can find information at this link on how to do it:
http://www.full-windows8.com/2012/03/how-to-disable-lock-screen-in-windows-8.html

Check out this easy tutorial too: http://techmell.com/how-to/turn-windows-8-lock-screen/